# WP7 Achievments, Without XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

this is a real quick question.
Is their a way i could access Achievements on the WP7 without being inside XNA?

or Maybe build an application that opens as a Regular App but then when a TouchDown Event is triggered Maybe open a XNA game?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to view achievements for your own game? or someone else's game?

Comment: neither, i am trying build an Application(NOT in XNA) and am wondering if i could still use The achievements Feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u need to integrate XNA application running in 3D I guess you can find the positive answer to your question here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XnaInWPF.aspx

You can integrate, with some work, XNA and WPF together at the rendering level.

If you need to access classes in XNA without the need to start the 3D rendering, sure, you just need to reference the XNA assemblies in your project and you can do wathever back-end logic you need.

And yes, as other people say, Achievement class throws NotSupportedException for all its members, both in the Windows version of XNA and in the XBox Indie game version.

As microsoft say:

"This class and all related methods and properties only retrieve a calculated result for titles approved to access Xbox LIVE Services through the Xbox LIVE Registered Developer Program. For Xbox LIVE Indie games, the properties in this class will not return a calculated result, and related methods will report a NotSupportedException."

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you so much, i wasn't sure if i called the references that they would properly work. but i guess they will, thanks again!

Comment: A side note: since WP7.1 (Mango), integration of Silverlight and XNA is directly supported by the mobile's APIs. Check [this tutorial](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-12-Mango-1.aspx) to see how it's done.

Comment: @ Elideb Thank you, i haven't gotten much into mango yet to see some of the functions this will help me with the integration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if it was possible to do what you want, Achievements *are* **ONLY** available to licensed Xbox Live games. To access the Achievement API you need to a have LiveId and be able to prop your achievements file to the Live network.

Comment: yeah, i understand that part and have that done already. i just want to be able to use the Achievement API for integration in a regular App to a Game app upon Selections being made.

Comment: With Mango, they have a Template for A hybrid App, Silverlight & XNA Merged. messing around with it lately, its awesome!